# How to call c++ source codes from Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, opencv, android-ndk

I have function implemented in C++ with several parameters and outputs. I want to use this function in my Android Studio Java code as a black box to pass necessary arguments and get results. The problem is that C++ function uses several libraries such as OpenCV together with other C++ implemented functions. I read about NDK and JNI and tried to do simple "Hello from C++" function call and it works. However, I do not understand how to install all libraries to C++ and how to put all necessary C++ codes.

Comment: add NDK library for your android studio

Comment: Dear @Krish, I added it but I want to know how to add all cpp files in my android studio and make them work. Also, cpp files uses several external libraries, so I want to know how to install them all into my android studio.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

Comment: follow above link it's very clear

Comment: For the external libraries, you need to include pre-built static `.a` files in your cpp project, compiled for each arch or you may include the source code directly, and write custom CMakeLists.txt to build the external library sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find nice tutorial about JNI [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html).